# Local adfs to client ADFS&AD redirction

Tags: adfs2.0

I have web app which uses WIF/ADFS claim fo ruathentication, i have set up one adfs and AD for that.

Now my need is i want to redirect and levarage client specific ADFS & AD for authentication.

App->Local ADFS->Client-1 ADFS->client -1 AD

App->Local ADFS->Client-2 ADFS->client -2 AD

so i want to do configuration for that client specific redirection in my Local ADFS, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you'll have an ADFS Federation Provider (FP) Issuer in your organization and your clients will have an ADFS (or other) Identity Provider (IdP) Issuer on their side.

To do this you would setup 2 Claims Provider Trusts (CPT) in your ADFS, one for Client1 and another for Client2.  When you start the new CPT wizard, you may be able to configure these using metadata provided by your clients ADFS (e.g. https://fs.client1.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml).  Your clients will then also need to configure your organization as a Relying Party Trust (RPT) in their ADFS.  If your metadata is available to them via a URL, they should be able to use the new RPT wizard in ADFS and configure their RPT for your organization with something like https://fs.myorg.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml.  Then, claims rules should be configured in these RPT's at your clients for claims to send to your organization and your CPT's for your clients should be configured to process the received claims from the clients.

Comment: Yes your answer make sense and i have done the same. But when my app is making a request to my org ADFS it itself is doing all and hence request is not going to client1 adfs at all.                               My Question here is how my org ADFS will know that it hasto forward this request to CLient-1 ADFS (this is not happening). Please correcct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: It may be that your home realm is cookied.  Try IE InPrivate or Chrome Incognito and when you hit your app are you then redirected to a home realm discovery page w/ the CPT's from your ADFS displayed?  If so, select one of them.

Comment: Currently have a deployment of ADFS 2.0 with a WIF web application.  WIF application is configured in ADFS 2.0 as a Reply Party.  Multiple Claim Providers are also configured within ADFS 2.0.  For SP-initiated, end-user request WIF application, redirected over to ADFS 2.0 system for home-realm discovery, redirected to Claims Provider configured IdP, authentication is performed, redirect back to ADFS with POST of SAMLResponse and then final redirect back to WIF application with FedAuth security token.  This is not working as expected (see below comment)

Comment: Now i have define SQL attribute store in (app=>adfs 2.0=>Multiple IDP(adfs/ad) ADFS2.0 which has rule whihc will take USerName as input and query the DB to get other Data and generate claims as desired values from SQL DB...and send. Now when i use above descrobed setup claim rule is not getting executed while coming back from IDP to ADFS2.0 its just sending  system generated fedauth cookie..not my claim rule generated token (whihc was working fine in this cas(app=>adfs2.0(AD as IDP same adfs was acting as IDP)

Comment: Putting the SQL attribute store issue aside for the moment.  Back on the home realm discovery page.  In the drop-down list you should have seen an IdP (i.e. CPT) for Client 1, Client 2 and your organization.  Was this the case?  You indicated "authentication was performed", was this authentication w/ your IdP or one of the Client IdP's?

Comment: yes, from the dropdown when i choose client1 it goes to client 1 ADFS/AD and ask for credentials and comes back to to my org adfs as well. this is happening but whatever rule i have written for my app(RP for local ADFS) is not been executing. thats the only concern now.

Comment: My first guess would be you're not receiving a claim from Client1 CPT that you're receiving from YourOrg CPT and which is being used by the claim rule querying the SQL attribute store in your RPT.  I would try setting your RPT to use a single claim rule to pass through all claims it receives (e.g. "c:[] => issue(claim = c);"). Then in your app, look at the claims you get from Client1 CPT and see if the claim needed to execute your SQL attribute store claim rule is present.

Comment: You could also stand up a Verify site to test this and for future use.  It would have its own RPT with this single claim rule also that passes through all claims it receives. Then, in the Verify site, output all the claims received.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Now after looking at your comment i have decide to write one "Tranform Incoming claim rule",now i just copied that rule language into custom rule that both works fine(Transform incoming claim rule/same rule copy into custom rule) ,its returning me a windowsaccount name but if i specified my custom rule with SQL attribute store its not working. any idea..if you want i'll provide you more detail on that.

Comment: My thought is you're SQL attribute store is not generating the claim type that your claim rule is executing on.